# Dealing with date and character variable in r

Tags: r

I have a column in my dataset called 'NAME'. Its in a character format. To make it use-able in R, do I have to convert it to a categorical variable? I'm thinking it will be factored into levels? Is that right?

Also I have a column called 'Date'. Also in a character format; in the order month and year e.g Jan 21. How do I convert this appropriately? I can't use as.Date(). I have tried the lubridate() function too but isn't working.i believe it has to do with my syntax.

Sorry I can't attach photos as it keeps displaying server error from my end.

Comment: See [How to make a great R reproducible example](
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Answer (score 0):

1. Most R functions that perform regressions (`lm`, etc.) are smart enough to treat character type variables as categorical variables, but if you prefer, you can convert it yourself with `as.factor()`.
2. You can convert a date in ISO format with `as.Date`.  The `lubridate` package has functions like `mdy` that can convert other formats.

```r
halloween <- as.Date("2022-10-31")
print(halloween)
#> [1] "2022-10-31"
class(halloween)
#> [1] "Date"

halloween <- lubridate::mdy("10/31/2022")
print(halloween)
#> [1] "2022-10-31"
class(halloween)
#> [1] "Date"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>